# Helm 3 chart install error: error validating data: apiVersion not set

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have a simple helm chart that will deploy an application to my local copy of kubernetes via docker desktop. If I use kubectl to deploy the yaml one file at a time things work correctly. However, when I try to create a helm chart for easier deployments I get the following error.

> helm install demo WebApi

> Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: apiVersion not set

The error seems to be saying that I am missing an apiVersion map in one or more of my YAML files. However, all of my files have what seems to be the correct apiVersions.

**Folder Structure**

```
charts
└── WebApi
    ├── Chart.yaml
    └── templates
        ├── deployment.yaml
        ├── ingress.yaml
        └── services.yaml
```

**Chart.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
version: 0.1.0
name: WebApi
appVersion: "1.0"
description: A Helm Chart for WebApi
type: application
```

**deployment.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-api
  labels:
    app: demo
    tier: demo-api
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: demo
          image: demo/image
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi" #128 MB
              cpu: "200m" #200 millicpu (.2 cpu or 20% of the cpu)
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /swagger/index.html
              port: 80
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 1
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /swagger/index.html
              port: 80
```

**ingress.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  rules:
    - host: demo.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: demo
              servicePort: 80
```

**service.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: demo
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

As you can see all of my YAML files have the required apiVersion map however the error still says they are missing. What corrections do I need to make in order for this to work as intended?

Comment: what does your Helm chart look like? Can you share it?

Comment: @Rico all the values are in the yaml above

Comment: Does it have the right file structure? how did you create it?  what's the point of using Helm if you are not even using the templating?

Comment: @Rico my apologies I misunderstood. Please see the folder structure that I added above.

Comment: Do you have any existing resource which is conflicting with this installation?

Comment: @Rico no this is a brand new install nothing existing.

Comment: I can install without problem. What's your helm version? And I notice that your folder name is `demo` while you use `helm install demo WebApi`, should it be `helm install WebApi demo`?

Comment: @Rico my helm version is v3.2.4. The demo was just me trying to obfuscate any sensitive information. The chart name matches the folder name. I will change that detail now.

Comment: When you execute `helm install webapi .` from `WebApi`  folder does it show the same error message? I managed to install your chart successfully.

Comment: @Dblock247 I created the same structure and able to install without errors. Are you posting the same content here? May be you are in different directory or trying different chart. Error says that you have to specified apiVersion

Comment: @KFC_ I thinking you are right. I am calling helm install from the wrong directory. When I call it from inside WebApi I get the following error. Error: failed to download "WebApi" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)

Comment: This works fine for me.

Comment: In my case, I was missing "apiVerson" itself.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

> Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error
> validating "": error validating data: apiVersion not set

This error means that the installation command was executed from wrong directory or wrong path to chart has been provided.

In order to install it, you have to either execute from the directory where `Chart.yaml` is placed or provide the path to this directory as an argument in `helm install` command, example from `WebApi` directory:

```
helm install webapi .
```

Comment: not sure why this is answer. if helm was run from incorrect folder, it would error `Error: Chart.yaml file is missing`

Answer (score 49):

I had a similar problem with the same error message, but not exactly the same problem.  The problem for me seems to have been a comment at the start of one of the helm templates.  It seems helm did not handle this case well.  When i moved the comment down a bit it worked.

Comment: I confirm this was also the the solution for me. Whoever voted you down on this should explain themselves.

Comment: helm also did not liked my entirely commented file, removed commented code, helped

Comment: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/templates/#comments-yaml-comments-vs-template-comments

Comment: Indeed, this is the case for me too. I had a comment in one of my templates

Comment: Great answers, solved my problem. I get impressed at how poor some error messages could be

Comment: It was exactly my case, one of the most non-obvious and dumb bugs I've ever faced with. 
Initially had file nginx-ingress.yaml, which **was starting** with 2 lines of comments (#). Had to remove them.
Helm v.3.7.2

Comment: Helm does not seem to deal with `#` comments very well.

Comment: This kind of helped me, I was using configmap.yaml (ConfigMap kind), which loaded an appsettings.json config file from filesystem using the .Files.Get directive.
Turns out I hadn placed the appsettings.json file inside the templates folder instead of with the chart.yaml. Moved it next to chart and the chart installed ok.

Comment: I had the exact same issue! Stupid error message by Helm/k8s. This answer helped me try moving the comments at least!

Answer (score 12):

I run `helm install anyname1 . --dry-run --debug` and got incomprehensible error messages.
then I run `helm template -f values.yaml . > deployChart.yaml`
and I saw some strange characters in the generated file.

My error: I created an additional file 'cronJob.yaml' inside templates using VS (visual studio) and added my content... I presume helm is not compatible -somehow- with the OS-windows encoding... anyways I hope this helps.

My solution: I copied an existing file, then renamed it and then I pasted my content.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I was adding .json file inside template directory. 
I ran `helm template -f values.yaml . > deployChart.yaml` and found that json file content present in `deployChart.yaml`.

Moving .json file outside of template directory resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, this is the right answer to me at least.

Answer (score 6):

I had same error message.  However my templates were generating broken output.

I fixed this by running first viewing `helm template .` This generated the output for review.  The problem was `---apiVersion: v2` was at the top of the generated chart.  The triple hyphens `---` are not intended.

To fix, changing `{{- end -}}` to `{{ end }}` at the bottom of my generated charts files. This allows for line breaks on multi-chart generated templates.

[image: Helm Chart Template Fix]

Comment: I had a similar issue, but it was at the beginning of the template, where an `{{- if ... -}}` block on the line after a comment was causing the next line to be appended to the end of the comment. Debugged using `helm template`. Resolved by changing it to `{{ if ... -}}`

Answer (score 2):

I came across this error while using Azure DevSpaces (which in turn uses helm for workload deployment). It turned out some of my template files had UTF-8 BOM and helm (in DevSpaces) was not able to handle it, although locally installed helm client was able to resolve the templates fine. I removed the BOM and that resolved the issue in DevSpaces.

Comment: This helped me resolving the issue. When I opened my affected yaml file in notepad++, Encoding was set to UTF-8 BOM, and when I changed it back to UTF-8, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

for my case deleting the readme file in the template folder solved the problem .

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. I was missing `a` from `apiVersion` in one of the yml files added to templates folder. A typo but worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

I included a library chart. Helm created Chart.lock file that caused the error.

Solution:
create .helmignore file in chart's directory with:

```
Chart.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

Test!

```
$ helm create k8s-helm

$ helm lint k8s-helm/
==> Linting k8s-helm/
[INFO] Chart.yaml: icon is recommended

1 chart(s) linted, 0 chart(s) failed

$ kubectl apply -f k8s-helm/ --dry-run=client
error validating "k8s-helm/Chart.yaml": error validating data: kind not set; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
error validating "k8s-helm/values.yaml": error validating data: [apiVersion not set, kind not set]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Linter did not reveal any errors, but there are problems with validation. How to be?

Helm launch!

```
$ helm install --debug --dry-run test-app k8s-helm/
```

Comment: Hey Mike, welcome to the community and thanks for the answer. Can you please add some more information to clarify your answer, so it's even easier to comprehend?

Comment: Hi @Rick! what are you having difficulty with?
In my answer, I demonstrated that we can make mistakes with our application's launch option when using helm : Deploying helm templates is only possible with the helm command, not kubectl .

Comment: Hey, we usually try to add some supporting information beyond the bare commands that explains the *why* and not just the *how*. You of course do not have to do that, but makes your response even better to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the NOTES.txt file under charts->template path.
Solution: file name is case sensitive, not suppose to give as Notes.txt, caps is a must because helm will be trying to interpret that file and it tries to  generate object for kubernetes.

Comment: your answer does not add anything more to an already answered question.

Answer (score 0):

All templates which are not yaml manifests shoud have `underscore` char at the beginning

```
Most files in templates/ are treated as if they contain Kubernetes manifests

The NOTES.txt is one exception

But files whose name begins with an underscore (_) are assumed to not have a manifest inside. These files are not rendered to Kubernetes object definitions, but are available everywhere within other chart templates for use.
```

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#partials-and-_-files

Answer (score 0):

If you're right about the helm command(s), this is 100% a problem with the helm chart.

Helm is not rendering the first line from your templates(commonly where we define apiVersion)

**To debug this issue quickly** follow the below steps:

Step-1:

- Template out your helm chart(use any of the commands)

```bash
# with default values, and currently in the chart directory
helm template . | tee debug.yaml

# with values file
helm template . --values=../production.yaml | tee debug.yaml

# only show specific templates file(useful if you're doubtful about a specific file)
helm template .  -s templates/configMap.yaml | tee debug.yaml
```

> NOTE: This command should not generate any error.

Step-2:

- dry-run this using kubectl

```bash
kubectl apply -f debug.yaml --dry-run=client
```

The command will fail when it reaches the errored resource.