# Error validating "values.yaml": error validating data: [apiVersion not set, kind not set]

Tags: azure-aks, splunk

I am trying to deploy again Splunk Connect for Kube https://github.com/splunk/splunk-connect-for-kubernetes on AKS after some changes but I get a weird error regarding the values.yaml file, namely: Error validating "values.yaml": error validating data: [apiVersion not set, kind not set].

Previously it was working fine. Here is the link to the yaml file:

```
 https://github.com/splunk/splunk-connect-for-kubernetes/blob/develop/helm-chart/splunk-connect-for-kubernetes/values.yaml
```

Any hint on how to solve it? I pasted the yaml on yaml lint and other validators and it tells me that it is valid.

```
global:
  logLevel: info
  splunk:
    hec:
      host:
      port:
      token: mytoken
      protocol: https
      endpoint: /endpoint/
      fullUrl: https://fullurl
      indexName:
      insecureSSL:
      clientCert:
      clientKey:
      caFile:
      indexRouting:
      consume_chunk_on_4xx_errors:
  kubernetes:
    clusterName: "cluster_name"
  prometheus_enabled:
  monitoring_agent_enabled:
  monitoring_agent_index_name:
  monitoring_agent_bind_address:
  metrics:
    service:
      enabled: true
      headless: true
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: false

    metricsPort: 24231
    interval: ""
    scrapeTimeout: "10s"

    additionalLabels: { }

splunk-kubernetes-logging:
  enabled: true
  logLevel:

  namespace:

  fluentd:
    path: /var/log/containers/*.log
    exclude_path:

  containers:
    path: /var/log
    pathDest: /var/lib/docker/containers
    logFormatType: json
    logFormat:
    refreshInterval:
    removeBlankEvents: true
    localTime: false
    enableStatWatcher: true

  k8sMetadata:
    podLabels:
      - app
      - k8s-app
      - release
    watch: true
    cache_ttl: 3600
    propagate_namespace_labels: false

  sourcetypePrefix: "kube"

  rbac:
    create: true
    openshiftPrivilegedSccBinding: false

  serviceAccount:
    create: true
    name:

  podSecurityPolicy:
    create: false
    apparmor_security: true
    apiGroup: policy

  splunk:
    hec:
      host:
      port:
      token:
      protocol:
      endpoint:
      fullUrl:
      indexName:
      insecureSSL:
      clientCert:
      clientKey:
      caFile:
      consume_chunk_on_4xx_errors:
      gzip_compression:
    ingest_api:
      serviceClientIdentifier:
      serviceClientSecretKey:
      tokenEndpoint:
      ingestAuthHost:
      ingestAPIHost:
      tenant:
      eventsEndpoint:
      debugIngestAPI:

  secret:
    create: true
    name:

  journalLogPath: /run/log/journal

  charEncodingUtf8: false

  logs:
    docker:
      from:
        journald:
          unit: docker.service
      sourcetype: kube:docker
    kubelet: &glog
      from:
        journald:
          unit: kubelet.service
      multiline:
        firstline: /^\w[0-1]\d[0-3]\d/
      sourcetype: kube:kubelet
    helloworld5:
      from:
        pod: helloworld5-5dc446c649-dwfmd
        container: helloworld5
    etcd:
      from:
        pod: etcd-server
        container: etcd-container
    etcd-minikube:
      from:
        pod: etcd-minikube
        container: etcd
    etcd-events:
      from:
        pod: etcd-server-events
        container: etcd-container
    kube-apiserver:
      <<: *glog
      from:
        pod: kube-apiserver
      sourcetype: kube:kube-apiserver
    kube-scheduler:
      <<: *glog
      from:
        pod: kube-scheduler
      sourcetype: kube:kube-scheduler
    kube-controller-manager:
      <<: *glog
      from:
        pod: kube-controller-manager
      sourcetype: kube:kube-controller-manager
    kube-proxy:
      <<: *glog
      from:
        pod: kube-proxy
      sourcetype: kube:kube-proxy
    kubedns:
      <<: *glog
      from:
        pod: kube-dns
      sourcetype: kube:kubedns
    dnsmasq:
      <<: *glog
      from:
        pod: kube-dns
      sourcetype: kube:dnsmasq
    dns-sidecar:
      <<: *glog
      from:
        pod: kube-dns
        container: sidecar
      sourcetype: kube:kubedns-sidecar
    dns-controller:
      <<: *glog
      from:
        pod: dns-controller
      sourcetype: kube:dns-controller
    kube-dns-autoscaler:
      <<: *glog
      from:
        pod: kube-dns-autoscaler
        container: autoscaler
      sourcetype: kube:kube-dns-autoscaler
    kube-audit:
      from:
        file:
          path: /var/log/kube-apiserver-audit.log
      timestampExtraction:
        format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
      sourcetype: kube:apiserver-audit

  image:
    registry: docker.io
    name: splunk/fluentd-hec
    tag: 1.3.2
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    usePullSecret: false
    pullSecretName:

  environmentVar:

  podAnnotations:

  extraLabels:

  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 200Mi

  bufferChunkKeys:  
  buffer:
    "@type": memory
    total_limit_size: 600m
    chunk_limit_size: 20m
    chunk_limit_records: 100000
    flush_interval: 5s
    flush_thread_count: 1
    overflow_action: block
    retry_max_times: 10
    retry_type: periodic
    retry_wait: 30

  sendAllMetadata: false

  tolerations:
    - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
      effect: NoSchedule

  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux

  affinity: {}

  extraVolumes: []
  extraVolumeMounts: []

  priorityClassName:

  kubernetes:
    clusterName:
    securityContext: false


  customMetadata:

  customMetadataAnnotations:

  customFilters: {}

  indexFields: []

  rollingUpdate:

splunk-kubernetes-objects:
  enabled: true
  logLevel:

  namespace:

  rbac:
    create: true

  serviceAccount:
    create: true
    name:
    usePullSecrets: false

  podSecurityPolicy:
    create: false
    apparmor_security: true
    apiGroup: policy

  priorityClassName:

  kubernetes:
    url:
    insecureSSL: false
    clientCert:
    clientKey:
    caFile:
    bearerTokenFile:
    secretDir:
    clusterName:

  objects:
    core:
      v1:
        - name: pods
        - name: namespaces
        - name: nodes
        - name: events
          mode: watch

  checkpointFile:
    name: kubernetes-objects.pos
    volume:

  splunk:
    hec:
      host:
      token:
      protocol:
      port:
      fullUrl:
      indexName:
      insecureSSL:
      clientCert:
      clientKey:
      caFile:
      caPath:      
      indexRouting:
      consume_chunk_on_4xx_errors:

  secret:
    create: true
    name:

  image:
    registry: docker.io
    name: splunk/kube-objects
    tag: 1.2.2
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    usePullSecret: false
    pullSecretName:

  environmentVar:

  podAnnotations:

  extraLabels:

  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 200Mi

  buffer:
    "@type": memory
    total_limit_size: 600m
    chunk_limit_size: 20m
    chunk_limit_records: 10000
    flush_interval: 5s
    flush_thread_count: 1
    overflow_action: block
    retry_max_times: 10
    retry_type: periodic
    retry_wait: 30

  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux

  tolerations: []

  affinity: {}

  customFilters: {}
  indexFields: []

splunk-kubernetes-metrics:
  enabled: true
  logLevel:

  namespace:

  rbac:
    create: true

  serviceAccount:
    create: true
    name:
    usePullSecrets: false

  podSecurityPolicy:
    create: false
    apparmor_security: true
    apiGroup: policy

  splunk:
    hec:
      host:
      port:
      token:
      protocol:
      fullUrl:
      indexName:
      insecureSSL:
      clientCert:
      clientKey:
      caFile:
      consume_chunk_on_4xx_errors:

  secret:
    create: true
    name:

  image:
    registry: docker.io
    name: splunk/k8s-metrics
    tag: 1.2.2
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    usePullSecret: false
    pullsecretName:

  imageAgg:
    registry: docker.io
    name: splunk/k8s-metrics-aggr
    tag: 1.2.2
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    usePullSecret: false
    pullsecretName:

  environmentVar:

  environmentVarAgg:

  podAnnotations:

  podAnnotationsAgg:

  extraLabels:

  extraLabelsAgg:

  resources:
    fluent:
      limits:
        cpu: 200m
        memory: 300Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 200m
        memory: 300Mi
  buffer:
    "@type": memory
    total_limit_size: 400m
    chunk_limit_size: 10m
    chunk_limit_records: 10000
    flush_interval: 5s
    flush_thread_count: 1
    overflow_action: block
    retry_max_times: 10
    retry_type: periodic
    retry_wait: 30

  aggregatorBuffer:
    "@type": memory
    total_limit_size: 400m
    chunk_limit_size: 10m
    chunk_limit_records: 10000
    flush_interval: 5s
    flush_thread_count: 1
    overflow_action: block
    retry_max_times: 10
    retry_type: periodic
    retry_wait: 30

  metricsInterval: 15s

  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux

  aggregatorNodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux

  tolerations:
    - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
      effect: NoSchedule

  aggregatorTolerations: {}

  priorityClassName:

  priorityClassNameAgg:


  affinity: {}

  kubernetes:
    kubeletAddress:
    kubeletPort:
    kubeletPortAggregator:
    useRestClientSSL: true
    insecureSSL: false
    caFile:
    bearerTokenFile:
    secretDir:
    clusterName:

  customFilters: {}

  customFiltersAggr: {}

  rollingUpdate:
```

Comment: You have alot of comments in your values.yaml. Have you looked into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63383447/21164658)? It sems that comments in values.yaml can cause problems with helm, if you use that.

Comment: I removed all comments and validate the file but I get the same error

Comment: You write that it worked, but broke "after some changes". What were those changes? What have you tried to do already?

Comment: I added a pod description (helloworld5) in the logs section. The weird thing is that I removed the file and created a new file with previous configurations and it does not work anymore.

Comment: Have you looked at your rendered files locally, using `helm template .`?

Comment: The command does not return any output. I don't understand why I am getting a validation error.